# diff files within dirs listing by date modified

Tags: diff

I was using MELD but it can't seem to sort by modification time, so I've been looking for a way to achieve something similar in terminal. I [found](https://superuser.com/a/601106/364893) a line of code

```
find /path/to/dir1  /path/to/dir2 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %p\n" | sort -r
```

which seems to output the differences (including new files) between directories.

I'm looking for a way to list *only* the modified files (not new or deleted) across two dirs and list them by most recently modified. I also need to limit output to N lines because my project is massive.

Comment: `ls -t` would give you files sorted by time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ls**

```
 ls -lrt /path/to/dir1  /path/to/dir2  | head -N
```

- note that you have directories as well.

**find**

you almost made it

```
find /path/to/dir1  /path/to/dir2 -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %p\n" | sort  | tail -N
```

- this will give you the N **newest** modified file. (oldest first)
- use  `... | sort -r | head -N` to have newest first.

Comment: Your find solution is glorious. Thanks for the ls solution too although the find solution worked much better.